# Путь в файлу для функции include

Tags: php, include

Доброго времени у меня проблем - не могу подключить на страницу один скрипт через функцию include 
к примеру искомый файл (rmk.php) лежит относительно корня в папке scrips
а тот файл в котором мы подключаем лежит относительно корнрня - maun/nex/page.php

пытаюсь подключить его так include(".../scrips/rmk.php"); эффекта нету, при том что если подключать тот же файл на страницу maun/example.php вот так include("../scrips/rmk.php"); то все заходит на ура! там какой то другой метод нужен??? так как то include("./../scrips/rmk.php"); ? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: так просто хочется относительные пути использовать\

Comment: создаешь `define('MAIN_ROOT', __DIR__)` в твоем главном файле, который лежит в корне, и везде где указываешь пути добавляешь include MAIN_ROOT . 'root/fileName.php'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключить файл можно следующим образом, поднявшись сначала на два уровня вверх, а потом спустившись в папку scripts

```
include("../../scrips/rmk.php");
```

Однако, лучше воспользоваться переменной окружения DOCUMENT_ROOT, которая сообщает абсолютный путь до корня вашего сайта

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/scrips/rmk.php");
```